# Fetch Recurring events from google calendar

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a class that fetch all the events from google calendar
but the code is not getting all events(like it is not fetching recurring events)I want to fetch each and every events which is already exists on google calendar. here my class for the same

```
import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.content.ContentUris
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.net.Uri
import android.provider.CalendarContract
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events
import android.text.format.DateUtils
import com.app.bosslevel.models.EventData
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


class Utility {
    companion object {
        var eventData = ArrayList<EventData>()
        var cursor: Cursor? = null

        open fun readCalendarEvent(context: Context): ArrayList<EventData> {

            val dtstart = "dtstart"
            val dtend = "dtend"
            var cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), arrayOf<String>(
                    "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                    "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation", "displayColor"
                ), ("($dtstart" + ">" + getCurrentDate() + " and "
                        + dtend) + "<" + getNextYearDate() + ")", null,
                "dtstart ASC"
            )!!

            cursor!!.moveToFirst()
            val CNames = arrayOfNulls<String>(cursor.getCount())

            eventData.clear()
            for (i in CNames.indices) {
                var endDate: Long = 0
                var desc: String = ""
                if (cursor.getString(4) != null) {
                    endDate = cursor.getString(4).toLong()
                } else {
                    endDate = 0
                }
                if (cursor.getString(2) != null) {
                    desc = cursor.getString(2)
                } else {
                    desc = ""
                }

                eventData.add(
                    EventData(
                        desc,
                        endDate,
                        cursor.getString(3).toLong(),
                        cursor.getString(1)
                    )
                )
                CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1)
                cursor.moveToNext()
                //println("!!!nameOfEvent--> = ${nameOfEvent[i]}${"!!!startDates = ${startDates[i]}"}${"!!!descriptions = ${descriptions[i]}"}${"!!!endDates = ${endDates[i]}"}")
            }
            println("!!!eventData = ${eventData}")
            return eventData
        }

        fun getCurrentDate(): Long {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().time.time
            println("!!!calendar.currentDate = ${getDate(calendar)}")
            return calendar
        }

        fun getNextYearDate(): Long {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1)
            val nextYearDate = calendar.time.time
            println("!!!tomorrow = ${nextYearDate}")
            println("!!!nextYearDate = ${getDate(nextYearDate)}")
            return nextYearDate

        }

        fun getDate(milliSeconds: Long): String? {
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
            )
            val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds)
            return formatter.format(calendar.getTime())
        }
    }
}
```

here is the codethat i tried to fetch recurring events

val path =
"" + getCurrentDate() + "/" + getNextYearDate()

```
        val dtstart = Events.DTSTART
        val dtend = Events.DTEND
        val eventsUriBuilder: Uri.Builder = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI
            .buildUpon()
        ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, getCurrentDate())
        ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, getNextYearDate())
        val eventsUri = eventsUriBuilder.build()
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        cursor = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(
                Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when/" + path),
                arrayOf<String>(
                    CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_ID,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.DESCRIPTION,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.DTEND,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_LOCATION,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.DISPLAY_COLOR,
                    CalendarContract.Instances.RRULE
                ),
                ("($dtstart" + ">=" + getCurrentDate() + " and "
                        + dtend + "<=" + getNextYearDate() + ")"),
                null,
                CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " ASC"
            )
```

```
Can any one please help me to fetch all the events from google calendar
```